# C# Renci.SshNet: Unable to upload files outside of SFTP root - slashes in current working directory are converted to backslahes

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

I'm using the following method to upload a text file to an SFTP server. When I set the destination path to root (`"/"`), the file uploads without issue. When I attempt to upload the file to a sub-directory of the root (`"/upld/"`), no file is uploaded, but there is also no error.

Interestingly, after calling `client.ChangeDirectory`, the `WorkingDirectory` property on client does update correctly, except that it's `"\upld"`. But the upload just doesn't work.

```
public void UploadSFTPFile(string sourcefile, string destinationpath)
{
    using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(this.host, this.port, this.username, this.password))
    {
        client.Connect();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourcefile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            client.UploadFile(fs, destinationpath + Path.GetFileName(sourcefile));
        }
    }
}

public void Caller()
{
    string localpath = "./foo.txt";
    string destinationpath = "/upld/"; // this does not upload any files
    //string destinationpath = "/"; // this uploads the file to root
    UploadSFTPFile(localpath, destinationpath);
}
```

Comment: Try using "/" as the remote directory separator instead of "\". SFTP specifies "/" regardless of the server's operating system.

Comment: I tried using "/" as the separator, but it didn't appear to make any difference. When I look at the values in the debugger, C# converts "\\" to "/" automatically.

Comment: *"C# converts "\\" to "/" automatically"* - That's non-sense. Show us your updated code.

Comment: By "C# converts "\\" to "/" automatically", I meant that calling client.ChangeDirectory("//upld//"); changes client.WorkingDirectory to "\upld". I updated the code to use "\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine for me.

The problem is probably, what you have observed: that your SFTP server (not C#) converts the slashes to backslashes, what confuses SSH.NET library, when assembling the full path of the uploaded file.

Note that the SFTP protocol (contrary to the FTP) does not have a concept of a working directory. The working directory is just simulated on a client-side by SSH.NET.

It's quite probable that you can solve your problem by using absolute paths in the `UploadFile` call, instead of using relative paths:

```
public void UploadSFTPFile(string sourcefile, string destinationpath)
{
    using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
    {
        client.Connect();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourcefile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            client.UploadFile(fs, destinationpath + Path.GetFileName(sourcefile));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code to match your suggestion, but I'm still experiencing the same behavior: The file fails to upload without an error message. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try backslashes? What is your SFTP server, btw?

Comment: I did try backslashes, but it didn't change the behavior. The SFTP server belongs to a client and it's hosted at edicomm.

Comment: Can you upload a file to a subfolder using any SFTP client application?

Comment: I am able to upload to a subfolder using FileZilla.

Comment: Show us a log file.

Comment: I think that I may have figured out the issue. I tried posting to another sub-folder and that worked fine. Also the test file that I uploaded via FileZilla disappear from the upld folder. I believe what's happened is that the client is  checking every second for new files and clearing them out before I can test. As far as I can see the code is working perfectly. Thank you for your help.